# How to determine the environment of your ember app

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

How can I access the environment of my ember application? My goal is to have a computed property called `isStaging` to check if the environment is staging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need a computed property, but you can just do this:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

import ENV from 'app-name/config/environment';

export default class extends Component {
  isStaging = ENV.environment === 'staging';
}

// or if you're on the old syntax:

export default Component.extend({
  isStaging: ENV.environment === 'staging'
});
```

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as correct (the checkbook). The points help motivate me to keep helping people :D

Answer (score 0):

This was the only way I could get environment detection to work

/config/environment.js

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  let ENV = {
    ...
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
         ...
         DEVELOPMENT: environment === 'development',
         TEST: environment === 'test',
         PRODUCTION: environment === 'production'
     },
     ...
   }
},
```

Then to access the environment anywhere in the project

```
import Ember from 'ember';

if(Ember.ENV.FEATURES.DEVELOPMENT) {
    // development
}

if(Ember.ENV.FEATURES.TEST) {
    // test
}

if(Ember.ENV.FEATURES.PRODUCTION) {
    // production
}
```